# Not able to break from while loop using getchar in C

Tags: c

I am new newbie, facing a basic problem, Not able to break while loop using getchar.Following code compiles successfuly but keeps displaying "Please enter NAME" only and keeps taking typed characters from KeyBoard but doesn;t break on typing enter for new line character :-(

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct employee
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char country[20];
}emp;

void getinfo(char *str, const char *param)
{
    int i;
    char ch;
    if (strcmp(param,"NAME" ) == 0)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter NAME \n");
    }
    else if(strcmp(param, "COUNTRY") ==0)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter COUNTRY \n");
    }
    while((ch==getchar())!= '\n')
    {
        str[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    str[i]= '\0';
}

int getage(int *age)
{
    printf("\n Please enter Age \n");
    scanf("%d",age);
}

int main(void)
{
    emp e1;
    getinfo(e1.name, "NAME");
    getinfo(e1.country, "COUNTRY");
    getage(&e1.age);
}
```

Please provide help.

Comment: You might find using [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) considerably easier to use for this particular code task.

Comment: `getchar()` returns an `int` with **very good** reason. You **really** should assign the result to a variable of type `int`. In other words: declare `ch` as `int ch;` *(this margin is too small for an explanation)*

Comment: You might consider passing an additional argument to `getinfo()` thus: `getinfo(e1.name, sizeof(e1.name)-1, "NAME");` then using that in your loop or an `fgets()` call to prevent buffer overrun.  You have no protection against a user entering too many characters, when nothing good will happen!

Answer (score 4):

The

```
while((ch==getchar())!= '\n')
```

should read

```
while((ch=getchar())!= '\n')
         ^
```

Otherwise, you're *comparing* the (uninitialized) value of `ch` to `getchar()`, instead of assigning the result of `getchar()` to `ch`.

Comment: I definitely agree if should be assignment. I missed it somewhere.Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
while((ch==getchar())!= '\n')
```

That line is currently an undefined operation since `ch` isn't assigned anything yet. Let's assume `ch==getchar()` is false, `false != '\n'` is true, since anything nonzero is true, and '\n' is greater than zero.

I assume you want to change the `==` in `ch==getchar()` to a single `=`.

Comment: Not anything above 0 is true. Anything other than zero is true.

Comment: @govindo Thanks, I never knew if negative numbers counted as true or false to C (and never ran into an edge case to need to look it up). Edited :)

Comment: I definitely agree if should be assignment. I missed it somewhere.Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have typed `while((ch==getchar())!='\n')`
This statement calls `getchar()` and compares to the garbage value of `ch`, and compares against `'\n'`

it will be usually `true`, so the while loop keeps on executing even though `ch` is assigned nothing
So, change it to `while((ch=getchar())!='\n')`

Comment: I definitely agree if should be assignment. I missed it somewhere.Many Thanks.